# Editing classes property from another class

Tags: c#, class, reference

Title is probably oversimplified, so please read the whole problem here.

I have 4 classes: level, player, mesh, and physics manager.
The manager is supposed to manage meshes. Player has one mesh (meshes contain multiple hitboxes). They are both loaded in level's constructor.

The goal is for player class to create it's own mesh, and then level is supposed to add that mesh to manager's list of meshes.

This is how I want my code to be structured (and how it almost is currently):

```
public class Player
{
    public SFPhyMesh Mesh { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        Mesh = new Mesh();
    }
}

public class PhysicsManager
{
    public List<Mesh> Meshes;

    public void AddMesh(Mesh mesh)
    {
        Meshes.Add(mesh);
    }
}

public class Level
{
    PhysicsManager physics;
    Player player;

    public Level()
    {
        player = new Player();

        physics = new PhysicsManager();
        physics.AddMesh(player.Mesh);
    }
}
```

Note that I left out all the less important parts.
Problem here is that the `AddMesh` function creates a copy to add to the list. I tried putting the `ref` keyword before it's parameter, but with no success. I also tried to create a public variable for player's mesh instead of a public property in combination with the `ref` keyword in `AddMesh` function, but with no success. Looks like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public SFPhyMesh Mesh;
    ...
}
public void AddMesh(ref Mesh mesh)
{
    Meshes.Add(mesh);
}
public class Level()
{
    player = new Player();

    physics = new PhysicsManager();
    physics.AddMesh(ref player.Mesh);
}
```

The only way this works is when `Level`'s constructor looks like this:

```
public class Level
{
    PhysicsManager physics;
    Player player;

    public Level()
    {
        var pMesh = new Mesh();

        player = new Player();
        player.Mesh = pMesh();

        physics = new PhysicsManager();
        physics.AddMesh(pMesh);
    }
}
```

I do not want the class level to be worrying about each player's/enemie's/entitie's mesh. I need each of these classes to be responsible for it's own mesh. But I struggle with providing the physics manager with the exact location in memory of the player's mesh.

I test this by adding gravity to the meshe's with tags "falling". In manager I only add this one mesh, and I put a breakpoint where gravity should be applied, and this breakpoint is hit. I see that the mesh that is being pulled by the gravity is changing it's velocity and position successfully, but I do not see that on screen. I see my player standing still, instead of falling. This can only mean that a copy of player's mesh is added to the list of meshes in physics manager, instead of the real player's mesh. Of course, this is only happening whith the first version of the level's constructor.

Is there a way to leave the level's constructor out of all this mesh business?

Comment: *"Problem here is that the AddMesh function creates a copy to add to the list."* - Where do you define the `Mesh` type?  Or is the type called `SFPhyMesh`?  Your naming of "mesh" types/variables is a bit misdirecting here, and that itself could be adding to your confusion.  Is the type a `class` or `struct`?  Because if it's a class then this code definitely is *not* creating a copy of the object when it's added to a `List<>`, since references don't work that way in C#.  You may have drawn a false conclusion somewhere else in your debugging/testing.

Comment: i will kms... let me know when you read this. I will then delete this question. the place of drawing the palyer sprite was a constant, not the meshe's position.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for a method AddPlayer on Level:

```
public class Level
    {
        PhysicsManager physics;

        public Level()
        {
            physics = new PhysicsManager();
        }

        public void AddPlayer(Player Player)
        {
            physics.AddMesh(Player.Mesh);
        }
    }
```

You need to call it in your code like:

```
Level myLevel = new Level();
myLevel.AddPlayer(newPlayer);
```

I need to say, I am confused that you create many objects in your constructors, this is not good practice.. The result is like you say, objects everywhere but no one is really in control. You need to really think about what object is in control of other objects.